# cms to implement survey module

Tags: java, php

I haven't worked with content management systems .. As per my project requirements There are questionnaires added at back end and user takes up the survey and answers the questionnaire.. The questions added at back end needs to be versioned.. can anyone suggest a cms which suits the requirement preferably in java or php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most major CMSs (Joomla and Drupal) have extensions that can be installed to allow such functionality.
[Joomla Extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/surveys/7188)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest php with Drupal with this extension

http://drupal.org/project/survey

If you need this to be hosted publicly, you can buy a domainname on say lunarpages or godaddy, and host it. It comes with php, mysql and drupal installed..